# \jobname, character codes and \detokenize

Tags: tex-core

I recently wanted to compare `\jobname` to a string (with the `xstring` package) and was rather surprised that the string never matched. Tho internet told me that I had to use `\detokenize` on the string. `\detokenize` is an e-TeX command, that

> when followed by a `<general text>`, expands to yield a sequence of character tokens of `\catcode` 10 (space) or 12 (other) corresponding to a decomposition of the tokens of the `<balanced text>` of the unexpanded `<general text>`;

Unfortunately, I do not own a copy of the TeXbook, so here are three questions:

- What is “balanced text”?
- Why does `\jobname` expand to the job name with “wrong” catcode?
- How did people compare `\jobname` to a string before e-TeX?

Comment: In the `old days` articles like these were useful http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb22-4/tb72wilson.pdf

Comment: @Yiannis. In older versions of `expl3` there was an expandable string-like test, based on the idea of dividing up the two arguments and using the `\if` primitive. It works quite nicely provided spaces are not important, but as we now require `\pdfstrcmp` it's been dropped. If it's of interest I can search back through the SVN and find it, but expect some mind-bending complexity!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Three questions there, but I think you'll be let off!

'Balanced text' means that the argument has to have balanced grouping characters, usually `{` and `}` pairs. This is because `\detokenize` requires an argument starting with a token with category code 1 (begin-group), in the same way as a token register. Indeed, you can do very similar things with a token register and with `\detokenize`:

```
\newtoks\mytoks
\def\test{stuff}
\mytoks\expandafter{\test}% \mytoks holds 'stuff' as letters
\detokenize\expandafter{\test}% Ouputs 'stuff' as 'other' tokens
```

On the category codes in `\jobname`, there are a number of places where you get a 'string' from TeX where everything except spaces has category code 12. You see the same with `\the\<somedimen>` and `\meaning` (more on the later in a moment). You'd have to ask DEK for the full story, but my understanding is that this 'string' approach is used so that no tokens are accidentally added to a control sequence name. There are places where if they were 'letters' then trouble might arise.

Finally, on the approach before e-TeX. As I said, `\jobname` is not the only place where you see 'string' output. In particular, `\meaning` does the same. So if you do

```
\def\testa{<whatever>}
\edef\testa{\meaning\testa}
\edef\testb{\jobname}
\edef\testb{\meaning\testb}
\ifx\testa\testb
...
```

the test will be true if the two names agree as lists of characters. There are variations on this method, see for example LaTeX's `\strip@prefix`, which can be used to make a 'string' without any prefix:

```
\makeatletter
\def\testa{<whatever>}
\edef\testa{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\testa}% Now a 'string'
```

(As pointed out by Martin Scharrer, LaTeX's `\@onelevel@sanitize` is the same as the above: `\@onelevel@sanitize\testa` would be equivalent to the last line above. To show what is going on it's clearer to see the `\meaning` but in use you'd pick `\@onelevel@sanitize`.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. (btw, do you mean `\strip@prefix` in the last paragraph?)

Comment: @Caramdir: Oops, yes I did. Sorted.

Comment: Joseph and @Caramdir: Just to point that out: The last code can be simplified a little using `\@onelevel@sanitize\testa`. It is defined as `macro:#1->\edef #1{\expandafter \strip@prefix \meaning #1}`, i.e. identical to the posted code.