# Can I convert a string to catcode 11?

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

In the TeX FAQ there's a way to test if the `jobname` is equal to something ([comparing the jobname](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-compjobnam)).  The difficulty of the naïve test is that the contents of the `\jobname` primitive are catcode 12 so to test if the `\jobname` is, say, `myfile` we need to create a macro containing the string `myfile` but with catcode 12 and use that to compare against `\jobname`.

This is all very well if you control the test.  But what if you don't?  What if there's some test deep in some package that you want to pass the `\jobname` (or some part of it) to and this test is against a predefined word of catcodes 11.

Is there some way, like `\meaning`, that can convert its contents to catcode 11?

*Added in edit*: An example of possible use has been called for.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117892/86}

\expandafter\includeonlylecture\expandafter{\jobname}

\begin{document}

\lecture{An Astonishing Result}{euclid}

\begin{frame}{Euclid's Astonishing Result}
\end{frame}

\lecture{A Boring Result}{pythagoras}

\begin{frame}{Pythagoras' Boring Result}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The intention being that:

```
pdflatex -jobname euclide lectures.tex
```

and

```
pdflatex -jobname pythagoras lectures.tex
```

produce different lectures.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/jobname-character-codes-and-detokenize

Comment: Are we allowed to use e-TeX? What do we do about non-letter characters?

Comment: e-TeX's `\scantokens` could be used or each character could be replaced by its letter counterpart. But the trouble with special characters (underscore, `@`, ...) remains. It is much more efficient and robuster to convert the other string to catcode 12 characters before the comparison.

Comment: Joseph: Yes, e-TeX is allowed.  As for non-letter characters, let's assume that I'm in a very controlled environment with regards to what I'm testing and can guarantee that `\jobname` (or an extracted part of it) consists *only* of letters.  Heiko: Granted, but consider this more of a "If I really have to do this, what do I do?".

Comment: Could you show a situation where you might want this?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Probably you should ask the maintainer of `beamer` to allow for string-based comparisons here :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Perhaps I ought to add the context that this came up because someone wanted to use the *idea* of my method of selecting a lecture using the filename but didn't want to use the complicated method that I actually use (described at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2569/86) so was trying to just use `\jobname` as the lecture name.  However, as I see now, that is similarly fraught with difficulties!

Comment: @AndrewStacey I've added how you can do for that problem. Of course a string (expanded) based comparison would be better, but that's for `beamer`'s maintainers.

Comment: I think this is a XY problem. IMHO, changing `jobname` for conditional typesetting is just wrong. Doesn't any of the LaTeX wrapper provide something similar to ConTeXt's ability of setting [modes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes#Setting_modes) from command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't understand very well the question; category code 12 is used exactly for avoiding problems with category codes and special characters.

With `\scantokens` you can do it: save the following code as `ncjob.tex` and run it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
  \everyeof{\noexpand}
  \endlinechar=-1
  \xdef\normaljobname{\scantokens\expandafter{\jobname}}
\endgroup

\def\test{ncjob}

\ifx\test\normaljobname\typeout{SUCCESS}\else\typeout{FAILURE}\fi

\stop
```

> SUCCESS

**Important note** This requires that the jobname contains only “safe characters”; something like `~` in the file name would make this die horribly.

---

A possibly safer way is to use `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn { NnV }
\NewDocumentCommand{\definenormaljobname}{O{\normaljobname}}
 {
  \tl_set_rescan:NnV #1 { } \c_job_name_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\definenormaljobname
\def\test{nc~job}\show\normaljobname

\ifx\test\normaljobname\typeout{SUCCESS}\else\typeout{FAILURE}\fi

\stop
```

Tested with the command line

```
pdflatex -jobname 'nc~job' ncjob
```

---

This is how your example could be managed; don't use special characters or spaces in the jobname passed from the command line (nor in the lecture labels, of course).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_set_rescan:Nnn { NnV }
\NewDocumentCommand{\includelecturefromjobname}{}
 {
  \tl_set_rescan:NnV \l_tmpa_tl { } \c_job_name_tl
  \exp_args:NV \includeonlylecture \l_tmpa_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\includelecturefromjobname


\begin{document}

\lecture{An Astonishing Result}{euclid}

\begin{frame}{Euclid's Astonishing Result}
\end{frame}

\lecture{A Boring Result}{pythagoras}

\begin{frame}{Pythagoras' Boring Result}
\end{frame}
```

---

### Note

As of September 2015, instead of `\c_job_name_tl` one should use

```
\c_sys_jobname_str
```

Comment: This is asking for trouble, if `\jobname` contains special characters, e.g. with active catcodes, ...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Hence my comment on the question: what are we expected to do in these cases :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: Sorry, missed that. :-(

Comment: I'd tried a few things with `\scantokens` before asking but none of them worked.  Care to explain why the `\everyeof{\noexpand}\endlinechar=-1` are there?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I know; I added a caveat.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I've added a question and answer on this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117906/use-of-everyeof-and-endlinechar-with-scantokens

Comment: @egreg `expl3` ensures that `\c_job_name_tl` will be quoted if it contains spaces, so you probably want `"nc job"` in your second example.

Comment: @JosephWright No, the test was with `pdflatex -jobname 'nc~job' ncjob.tex`

Comment: @egreg Ah, you've quoted it on the command line: I was thinking `pdflatex "nc job.tex"` (easy enough to do using an IDE).

Comment: I think you've covered all the reasonable uses now!

Answer (score 5):

This allows the filename to have special characters, and still do the comparison (in this case, everything is converted to catcode 12 for the comparison)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\def\display#1{\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}
\def\comparenames#1{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\display{#1}}{\display{\comparetest}}}{T}{F}}
\begin{document}
\def\comparetest{myfile}

\def\jbnm{myfile}
\comparenames{\jbnm}

\def\jbnm{\$&o)-}
\comparenames{\jbnm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Save this file as cxviiviiicxcii.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Save this file as cxviiviiicxcii.tex

\begin{document}


\def\alltoletter {%
    \count 255 0
    \loop
    \catcode\count255 11
    \ifnum\count 255 < 255 \advance \count 255 1 \repeat }

\def\convert #1\to #2{%
        \begingroup
          \everyeof{\noexpand}%
          \endlinechar -1
          \alltoletter
          \edef\x{\scantokens\expandafter{#1}}%
% earlier silly stuff (sorry):  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
        \expandafter\endgroup
        \expandafter\def\expandafter #2\expandafter{\x}%
    }%


\def\myname {cxviiviiicxcii}%

\convert\jobname\to\jobnameconverted

converted: \ifx\myname\jobnameconverted EQUAL\else UNEQUAL\fi

unconverted: \ifx\myname\jobname EQUAL\else UNEQUAL\fi

\begingroup
\escapechar -1
\xdef\testtwoA {\string\abcdef}
\endgroup

\convert\testtwoA\to\testtwoAconverted

\def\testtwoB {abcdef}

converted: \ifx\testtwoB\testtwoAconverted EQUAL\else UNEQUAL\fi

unconverted: \ifx\testtwoB\testtwoA EQUAL\else UNEQUAL\fi
\end{document}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: A comment: if the macro whose contents are to be converted to catcode 11 contains a control sequence, say `\abc` then it seems that `\scantokens` will transform it into `\abc ` where the first four have catcode 11, and the space is *also* of catcode 11; except if this `\abc` is the last thing just before the closing brace in the initial definition of the to-be-converted macro (contents), then no space. So the `\alltoletter` should possibly end in `\catcode32 10`, in order for the spaces produced by `\scantokens` to be standard, thus easing up use of the `\convert` thing.