# How are tokenized arguments of a macros?

Tags: macros, tex-core

In the following pdftex example we make verbatim environment inside "...", i.e., all special characters get catcode 12. The problem is with `{`:

```
\def\setverb{\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12}\dospecials}

\catcode`\"=\active
\def"#1"{%
  \leavevmode\hbox{%
    \setverb
    \tt
    \endlinechar=-1 \scantokens{#1}%
  }%
}

hello "{" world
\bye
```

Why it gives this error?

```
(./test.tex
Runaway argument?
{" world 
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of ".
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<to be read again> 
                   \bye 
l.13 \bye

?
```

Should not it tokenize arguments until it encounters the second `"`?

How to make `\def"#1"{...}` work in all cases?

Comment: Well braces can still group arguments, e.g. `\def"#1#2"{arg1: #1 arg2: #2}` and `"{abc}d"` will give `arg1: abc arg2: d`. So braces must be balanced. Check the definition of `\verb` in latex.ltx for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When TeX finds `"`, it looks for the next `"` *at the same group level*, which it doesn't find, because `{` still has its usual category code 1. Since `"` is not `\long`, the first `\par` token triggers the error.

You have to split processing in two parts: first set the category codes, then absorb the argument.

---

The parameter text for a macro can define both delimited or undelimited arguments, but, in any case, TeX keeps track of `<left brace>` and `<right brace>` (meaning explicit character tokens of category code 1 and 2 respectively).

So, for instance,

```
\def\foo (#1,#2){#1-#2}
```

defines a macro that *must* be followed by `(`<sub>12</sub>, with the first argument delimited by `,`<sub>12</sub> and the second argument delimited by `)`<sub>12</sub>.

However, the call

```
\foo({(a,b)},c)
```

would absorb `#1` as `{(a,b)}` (and the braces would be removed), and `#2` as `c`.

In your case, only balanced braces would take you home.

Answer (score 3):

I'd not use `\scantokens` and not even make `"` scan for an argument at all but set the appropriate catcodes in a group and let `"` to `\endgroup` (also works with Knuth TeX).

```
\def\setverb{\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12}\dospecials}

\catcode`\"=\active
\def"{\begingroup\setverb\tt\let"=\endgroup}

hello "{}%~&^_$#\" world
\bye
```

If you want to have it in a box, use some two-stage method.

```
\def\setverb{\def\do##1{\catcode`##1=12}\dospecials}

\catcode`\"=\active
\def"{\begingroup\setverb\tt\doverb}
\def\doverb#1"{\hbox{#1}\endgroup}

hello "{}%~&^_$#\" world
\bye
```

---

Knuth uses something similar in `manmac.tex`.

```
\chardef\other=12
\def\ttverbatim{\begingroup
  \catcode`\\=\other
  \catcode`\{=\other
  \catcode`\}=\other
  \catcode`\$=\other
  \catcode`\&=\other
  \catcode`\#=\other
  \catcode`\%=\other
  \catcode`\~=\other
  \catcode`\_=\other
  \catcode`\^=\other
  \obeyspaces \obeylines \tt}

\catcode`\|=\active
{\obeylines \gdef|{\ttverbatim \spaceskip\ttglue \let^^M=\  \let|=\endgroup}}
```

Comment: Which is a simplified version of what `\verb` does in LaTeX.

Comment: The reason that I use `\scantokens` is to be able to use active quotes in arguments to a macro. See this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317879/how-is-catcode-handled Your solution will not work in such case.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Okay, but then you can't use it to typeset verbatim content in the argument of a macro.  I think that's just not possible.  The unmatched brace is kind of harmless, but try forwarding `%`.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko You could typeset the verbatim material at global scope and save it in a box.  Then you can pass the box to a macro without having to worry.