# What does ARGS in pdflatex --help mean? / How does the command-line invocation of mylatexformat works?

Tags: tex-core

While researching on precompiling the preamble, usually the command to create the format file goes something like

```
pdftex -ini -jobname="foo" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx foo.tex
```

Reading `pdftex --help`, I understand that:

```
-jobname=STRING         set the job name to STRING
-ini                    be pdfinitex, for dumping formats; this is implicitly
                          true if the program name is `pdfinitex'
```

and the remaining argument is specified by this line

```
   or: pdftex [OPTION]... &FMT ARGS
```

So `FMT` is `pdflatex`, and `ARGS` is `mylatexformat.ltx foo.tex`.

Question:

- What does `ARGS` specify here?
- Why does it result in the preamble being generated?
- Also, where is the documentation?
- Why does the documentation of `mylatexformat` suggest using triple quotes for the `foo.tex` part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of command line

```
tex &FMT ARGS
```

comes from ancient times, when the Unix command line was not as common as today, and leads to the classical TeX behavior: after reading the `&FMT` format, TeX scans the first letter; if it is a `\` then the rest of command line is interpreted as a first line of the document. This is not exactly your example: the first letter is `m` in your example, so TeX interprets the following word (without spaces) as a file name and does `\input mylatexformat.ltx`. This is a very common situation; what is uncommon is tha the file you are using doesn't have the `\end` or `\dump` primitive (and the `\end` or `\dump` primitives are not expanded from used macros). This is a case when TeX reads next data from the rest of the command line and then from the terminal. The `mylatexformat` file ends by
`\expandafter\input\endinput`, so the `\input` command is invoked, but its parameter isn't given in the file `mylatexformat.ltx`, so TeX tries to read the parameter from the rest of the command line, and that means that `\input foo.tex` is done.

About quotes. The command interpreter removes them and interprets the text inside it more verbose. Try `echo """hello"""`, for example. It prints `hello`. But I don't know why they are recommended in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I just need to stare at the documentation a bit more carefully.

> ```
> Usage: pdftex [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
>    or: pdftex [OPTION]... \FIRST-LINE
>    or: pdftex [OPTION]... &FMT ARGS
> ```
>
> Run pdfTeX on TEXNAME, usually creating TEXNAME.pdf.
> Any remaining COMMANDS are processed as pdfTeX input, after TEXNAME is read.
> If the first line of TEXNAME is %&FMT, and FMT is an existing .fmt file,
> use it.  Else use `NAME.fmt', where NAME is the program invocation name,
> most commonly `pdftex'.
>
> Alternatively, if the first non-option argument begins with a backslash,
> interpret all non-option arguments as a line of pdfTeX input.
>
> Alternatively, if the first non-option argument begins with a &, the
> next word is taken as the FMT to read, overriding all else.  **Any
> remaining arguments are processed as above.**
>
> If no arguments or options are specified, prompt for input.

In other words, `ARGS` is the "any remaining arguments", which means written explicitly it would be

```
Usage: pdftex [OPTION]... [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
   or: pdftex [OPTION]... \FIRST-LINE
   or: pdftex [OPTION]... &FMT [TEXNAME[.tex]] [COMMANDS]
   or: pdftex [OPTION]... &FMT \FIRST-LINE
```

Which means `mylatexformat.ltx` becomes the file name `[TEXNAME[.tex]]`, and `foo.tex` becomes `[COMMANDS]` i.e.
"processed as pdfTeX input".

---

### Experiment to deduce the exact behavior (TeX Live on Linux only)

<sub>(without referring to the source code of `pdftex-changes.pdf`)</sub>

Some experiment to see how the "commands" work:

```
echo '\edef\a{' > a.tex
pdftex a.tex 'bc}' </dev/null
```

gets "runaway definition" error. (this one is clear: [Use of \everyeof and \endlinechar with \scantokens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117906/250119))

```
echo '\edef\a{\noexpand' > a.tex
pdftex a.tex 'bc}\message{|\a|}' </dev/null
```

shows `\a` gets assigned `bc`, which means that after the `EOF`, the commands of the are put as a "line of TeX code", as explained.

Instead of `\noexpand` we can also use

```
echo '\endlinechar=`d\edef\a{' > a.tex
echo 'bc' >> a.tex
echo 'bc\noexpand%' >> a.tex
pdftex a.tex 'bc' '}\message{|\a|}\show' </dev/null
```

This outputs `|⟨space⟩ bcdbcbc ⟨space⟩|`, and the `\show` at the end does not show anything or give any error.

If there are multiple arguments, they're concatenated with a space, **not** interpreted as multiple lines of TeX codes.

(the above is equivalent to executing the following TeX code

```
\endlinechar=`d\edef\a{ ■¹
bc ■²
bc\noexpand% ■³
⟨EOF⟩
bc ∘⁴ }message{|\a|}\show ■⁵
```

Analysis: (each `■` represents a `endlinechar`)

- ■¹ is already fixed to be equivalent to char 13 as the first line is read.
- ■² becomes the character `d`.
- ■³ gets commented out.
- ∘⁴ is **not** endlinechar, it's just a space.
- We will look at `■⁵` later.

We can experiment a bit more:

```
pdftex '\catcode13=12\def~{\show}~' </dev/null
```

results in `the character ^^M.`

which means a **"(untokenized) character" with character code 13** is appended after the "pseudo-line".

---

### Remark on the code of `mylatexformat.ltx`

Unlike `\edef`, commands such as `\input` (the primitive one) can work across the EOF boundary:

```
echo '\message{hello world!!!}' > "hello world.tex"
echo '\input' > a.tex
pdftex a.tex '"hello world.tex"' </dev/null
```

(this inputs the content of `hello world.tex` to print out the message)

and the (expandable) `\endinput` is actually useless as long as it's already at the end of the file.

---

### Remark on the note in `mylatexformat.ltx` documentation

On the other point, I suspect that the triple-quote recommendation is because
[that's the way to escape quotes in commands in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760545/escape-double-quotes-in-parameter#15262019),
although I haven't tested that.

So the TeX code being executed becomes something like

```
\input "file name.tex"
```

instead of

```
\input file name.tex
```

obviously the latter wouldn't work.

Also, as mentioned in a comment in `mylatexformat.ltx`:

```
%% Trick lookahead to allow mylatex.ltx and the document filename to be
%% given on the same command line. (initex &latex mylatex.ltx {abc.tex})
\expandafter\input\endinput%
\endinput
```

As such invocations such as

```
pdftex -ini -jobname="foo" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "{foo.tex}"
```

would also work.

---

### Allow getting the filename without extra quoting

Side note, with the above knowledge:

- In the TeX code, it's impossible to distinguish between the case the user writes

  ```bash
  pdftex file.tex firstargument secondargument
  ```

  and

  ```bash
  pdftex file.tex "firstargument" "secondargument"
  ```

  as in both cases the arguments are concatenated with a space.
- We can design a function that `\input` from the file whose name is given on the command-line, without needing an additional quote,
  as long as the filename is the whole thing on the command-line.

  ```bash
  cat > a.tex << 'EOF'
  \catcode `\^^M 2 %
  \def \process {\catcode `\^^M 5 \input {\filename}}%
  \afterassignment \process %
  \edef \filename {\noexpand%
  EOF

  # alternatively:
  cat > a.tex << 'EOF'
  \catcode `\^^M 12 %
  \def \process #1^^M{\catcode `\^^M 5 \input {#1}}%
  \expandafter \process \noexpand%
  EOF

  # then these can be used (as mentioned above, they're equivalent and indistinguishable)
  pdftex a.tex hello world.tex </dev/null
  pdftex a.tex "hello world.tex" </dev/null
  ```

  Additional precautions are required to handle `{` or `}` in file names, if needed (for academical purposes only, probably.)