# Biblatex field values and comparisons

Tags: biblatex, programming, debugging

I would like to change the behavior of printing author names based on the hash field in biblatex. This mwe should demonstrate what I am having difficulty understanding.

### MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, punctfont=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe_design_2013,
  author = {Doe, John B.},
  journaltitle = {Acme Society Journal},
  date = {2013-03-08},
  title = {Design of alpha widgets},
  volume = {1},
  issue = {1},
  pages = {10}
}
@article{doe_alpha_2014,
  author = {Smith, Jane J. and Doe, John B.},
  journaltitle = {Acme Society Journal},
  date = {2014-03-08},
  title = {Alpha widgets in space},
  volume = {2},
  issue = {1},
  pages = {5}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcommand*{\mystr}{7ba24cb78eaec483f680a08422f4d516}
\newcommand*{\myhash}{7ba24cb78eaec483f680a08422f4d516}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{
  \iffieldequals{hash}{\myhash}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}
}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{
  \iffieldequalstr{hash}{7ba24cb78eaec483f680a08422f4d516}
  {\savefield{hash}{\myhash}\mkbibbold{#1}}
  {#1}
}
\begin{document}

Commands equal: \ifdefequal{\myhash}{\mystr}{True}{False}

Replacement text equal: \ifdefstrequal{\myhash}{\mystr}{True}{False}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Test}]

Commands equal: \ifdefequal{\myhash}{\mystr}{True}{False}

Replacement text equal: \ifdefstrequal{\myhash}{\mystr}{True}{False}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\end{document}
```

### Output:

[image: mwe output]

---

I understand that the initial value for \myhash is not the same as the biblatex hash field, even if their string values are the same as the initial *J.B.* is not bold and the next occurrence is.

What I would like to understand is:

1. How do I compare the string value of a biblatex field to the string value of a command?
2. What is the value of the biblatex hash field
3. How do I determine what the value of a command or biblatex field actually is?

I feel like I am missing a core concept, and a better means of debugging issues in LaTeX.

(I am aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73136/make-specific-author-bold-using-biblatex), but my question is more about LaTeX/biblatex programing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `\detokenize` the string before assigning it to your macro.  This is easiest to do via an `\edef`:

```
\edef\myhash{\detokenize{7ba24cb78eaec483f680a08422f4d516}}
```

Now `\iffieldsequals` has a chance of succeeding.  Compare this with the nice discussion at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6833/15925

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=phys, punctfont=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{doe_design_2013,
  author = {Doe, John B.},
  journaltitle = {Acme Society Journal},
  date = {2013-03-08},
  title = {Design of alpha widgets},
  volume = {1},
  issue = {1},
  pages = {10}
}
@article{doe_alpha_2014,
  author = {Smith, Jane J. and Doe, John B.},
  journaltitle = {Acme Society Journal},
  date = {2014-03-08},
  title = {Alpha widgets in space},
  volume = {2},
  issue = {1},
  pages = {5}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newcommand*{\mystr}{7ba24cb78eaec483f680a08422f4d516}
\edef\myhash{\detokenize{7ba24cb78eaec483f680a08422f4d516}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{
  \iffieldequals{hash}{\myhash}{\mkbibbold{#1}}{#1}
}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{
  \iffieldequals{hash}{\myhash}
  {\mkbibbold{#1}}
  {#1}
}
\begin{document}

Commands equal: \ifdefequal{\myhash}{\mystr}{True}{False}

Replacement text equal: \ifdefstrequal{\myhash}{\mystr}{True}{False}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Test}]

Commands equal: \ifdefequal{\myhash}{\mystr}{True}{False}

Replacement text equal: \ifdefstrequal{\myhash}{\mystr}{True}{False}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\detokenize` is solving some other problems I have been having. This was the major concept that I was missing, thanks.