# How can I check if the filename of a LaTeX document contains a string?

Tags: conditionals, jobname

I am preparing a LaTeX beamer presentation for students. I am looking for a simple way to create two versions of my presentation.

One version for the Students, which just contains the text of the tasks they get for homework and an other one for me which also contains the solution.

So I have created a macro that is intended to check if the file name contains "student".
If it does, the macro outputs nothing, and if it does not, the argument is passed:

```
\newcommand{\hausaufgabenLoesung}[1]{%
    \IfSubStringInString{student}{\jobname}{}{#1}%
}
```

But this does not work as intended.
No matter how I name the file, the conditional always goes to the false-expression.
I think the `\jobname` macro returns something which can not be processed by `\IfSubStringInString` but I have no other idea how I could approach this.

If I replace the `\jobname` macro in the conditional with a fixed string, it works as intended but this would render it fairly useless.

I used `\jobname` to avoid including the currfile-package, but with the currfile-macros I get the same behaviour. I am using texlive 2014 pdflatex on Linux and Windows.

Anyone here got a hint for that?

Here is a minimal complete example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{substr}

\newcommand{\hausaufgabenLoesung}[1]{%
    \IfSubStringInString{student}{\jobname}{}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \jobname
        \item Visible in both files
        \hausaufgabenLoesung{\item Solution not in the student file}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863).

Comment: Perhaps you should try `\IfSubStr` from `xstring` package. And you mean `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, not vice versa ;-)

Comment: Thanks! But I get the same behaviour with the changed macro: `\newcommand{\hausaufgabenLoesung}[1]{\IfSubStr{\jobname}{student}{}{#1}}`

Comment: Perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101479/how-to-build-two-different-tex-files-from-same-tex-file?lq=1 may solve the problem you care about - but not with the method you're trying.

Comment: The chars in \jobname all have \catcode 12. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/jobname-character-codes-and-detokenize.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The characters in `\jobname` have category code 12 and this defies `substr`, which uses an `\ifx` based comparison. You can simply stringify `student`, using the fact that `substr` commands fully expand their arguments:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{substr}

\newcommand{\hausaufgabenLoesung}[1]{%
    \IfSubStringInString{\detokenize{student}}{\jobname}{}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \jobname
        \item Visible in both files
        \hausaufgabenLoesung{\item Solution not in the student file}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get if the file name doesn't contain `student`:

[image]

This is what I get if the file name contains `student`:

[image]

---

A classical solution (without `\detokenize`):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{substr}

\begingroup\escapechar=-1
\xdef\studentstring{\string\student}
\endgroup

\newcommand{\hausaufgabenLoesung}[1]{%
    \IfSubStringInString{\studentstring}}{\jobname}{}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \jobname
        \item Visible in both files
        \hausaufgabenLoesung{\item Solution not in the student file}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

A solution with regular expressions (vastly generalizable):

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\hausaufgabenLoesung}{m}
 {
  \regex_match:nVF {student} \c_sys_jobname_str {#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnF { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \jobname
        \item Visible in both files
        \hausaufgabenLoesung{\item Solution not in the student file}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! `\IfSubStringInString{\detokenize{student}}{\jobname}{}{#1}` did the trick to me! After Ulrikes comment I have already heard from `\detokenize` but I tried to use it on `\jobname` instead of my string. Guess I have to read about that again. Thank you!

Comment: Because I find it to be more elegant, I created an environment for the same purpose. I use the `comment`-Package for the ability to hide the environment. The `environ`-Package seems to be incompatible with `lstlisting`. `\IfSubStr{\jobname}{\detokenize{student}}{\excludecomment{hausaufgabenLoesung}}{\newenvironment{hausaufgabenLoesung}{}{}}`

Comment: As of September 2015, `\c_job_name_tl` should become `\c_sys_jobname_str`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Do you have a source for that? I am interested in the reason for the change.

Comment: @Andi The team restructured some code, adding some modules, among which `sys` for "runtime" things. After an update to expl3 I always look for the changes.

Comment: @egreg Can you comment on why we need to define a new variant of `regex_match`? Especially after we used it to define `\hausaufgabenLoesung`.

Comment: @Franz The second argument we need to pass is not `\c_job_name_tl` (but nowadays it should be `\c_sys_jobname_str`) but its value. So the `V` variant will do the right thing.

Comment: @egreg I get that we want to match the actual string `student` (`n`) against the value of `\c_sys_jobname_str` (`V`), i.e., why we use `\regex_match:nVF` . What I do not understand is why we need `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnF { nV }`

Comment: @Franz Because the variant is not predefined

Comment: @egreg Aha! We define it later than we use it (speaking in terms of code lines). The newly generated variant is exactly the one, that we need! I think I got it now.

Comment: @Franz The important thing is that the variant is defined before any usage of the function needing it. It can be in a “define needed variants” section of the code; in this case the appropriate spot seems just to be after the `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: @egreg Yep. Got it now. Quite obvious actually ... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

According to Ulrike Fischer's comment `\jobname` consists of 'wrong' catcode characters, a direct comparison is not possible with some hacks. One workaround is to write the jobname to a dummy file and read it immediately back to some `\def\....` macro, say `\RealJobName`. This can be used as one string placeholder for the tests.

The `\AtBeginDocument{}` environment hook automatically does this and 'returns' the jobname in `\RealJobName` for later use.

Both approaches with `substr` and `xstring` work.

### studentname.tex

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{substr}
\usepackage{xstring}%

\newcommand{\hausaufgabenLoesung}[1]{%
    \IfSubStringInString{student}{\RealJobName}{}{#1}%
}


\newcommand{\hausaufgabenLoesungXString}[1]{%
\IfSubStr{\RealJobName}{student}{}{#1}%
}


\gdef\RealJobName{}%

\newwrite\mywrite%
\newread\myread%
\AtBeginDocument{%
\immediate\openout\mywrite\jobname.dum%
\immediate\write\mywrite{\jobname}%
\immediate\closeout\mywrite%
\immediate\openin\myread=\jobname.dum%
\read\myread to \RealJobName%
\immediate\closein\myread%
}%

\begin{document}




\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \jobname
        \item Visible in both files
          \hausaufgabenLoesung{\item Solution not in the student file}
          \hausaufgabenLoesungXString{\item Solution not in the student file}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```