# Using the document title to get the correct date

Tags: date, jobname

I create a lot of handouts and the like for my students using LaTeX. I find that I forget to update the date field, and so I often give out handouts with the incorrect date on the top. This is a bit of a nuisance and would be easily fixed by me being slightly less lazy.

However, I save the source files in the format `[YY-MM-DD]_DocumentType.tex`, e.g., `[18-02-14]_Handout.tex` and `[18-02-14]_Plan.tex` are the handout and plan for my class tomorrow.

Does anyone know of a way that I could use the name of the file to automatically generate the corresponding date within the compiled document?

Comment: Perhaps related: [How can I check if the filename of a LaTeX document contains a string?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197330/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created the file `[18-02-14]_james.tex` (on February 13).

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\splitjobname[#1-#2-#3]#4\relax{%
  \year=\numexpr2000+#1\relax
  \month=#2
  \day=#3
}
\expandafter\splitjobname\jobname\relax

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```

[image]