# Change the name of the *.bbl output file of BibTex?

Tags: bibtex, texstudio

This might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), but I'm trying to compile two PDFs from the same source. One containing exercises, called `a.pdf`, and another which additionally includes the answers, called `a-solutions.pdf`.

I'm using TexStudio on Windows and have succeeded in creating the two files using the following configuration for `pdflatex` (simplified for the sake of the example):

> `pdflatex.exe "\newif\ifsolutions\solutionsfalse\input{%.tex}" | pdflatex.exe "\newif\ifsolutions\solutionstrue\input{%.tex}" --jobname=%-solutions`

Basically, I'm running `pdflatex` twice, once with a boolean variable (`solutions`) set to false, and a second time with the variable set to true.

However, I'm not able to resolve the bibliography references for the second file. I don't know how to create the necessary `a-solutions.bbl` file required for the second (and third) pass of pdflatex.

Here's my current `bibtex` configuration in TexStudio:

> `bibtex.exe %  | bibtex.exe %-solutions.aux`

Again, I'm trying to run things twice: once for `a.pdf` and once for `a-solutions.pdf`. However, only `a.bbl` is created. How can I also create `a-solutions.bbl`?

Is it even possible to solve this?

**Note:** Ideally I want a solution that only requires modification to my TexStudio configuration and/or my source files. That is, I do not want to rely on external tools or build scripts.

Comment: Why does it actually fail? When I do `pdflatex --jobname XXX`, then this will generate `XXX.aux`, and then `bibtex XXX` will generate `XXX.bbl`, which will be used when doing again `pdflatex --jobname XXX`.

Comment: Unrelated: A solution different from using a switch is to control the behavior (with/without solutions) via the jobname, see [https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197330](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197330/110998). So you would either make a copy of the file to something ending with `solutions`, or you would use the option `--jobname` as you already do. The difference is that you don't need the switch `\ifsolutions`. BTW, the option `--shell-escape` is unrelated to your question.

Comment: @gernot Hmm, maybe I don't understand how the bibtex command works, but when I run it (through TexStudio), it doesn't seem to pick up on the `a-solutions.aux` file created in the previous run of pdflatex. Thus, it only creates `a.bbl`, but not `a-solutions.bbl`. So is `bibtex %-solutions.aux` the right command to tell bibtex to "use this aux file, and spit out a bbl file with a matching name"?

Comment: @gernot Regarding `--shell-escape': thanks, removed!

Comment: @gernot You were right! It turns out that `bibtex %-solutions**.aux**` was in fact the *wrong* command, and simply removing the **.aux** extension fixed the problem. If you want to write this up as an answer I'll happily accept. Else I'll just do it myself in a little while. Thanks!

Comment: Gz for solving the problem! May I suggest that you write the answer yourself, with all details that are relevant to the problem? In fact, under Linux, `bibtex XXX.aux` works as well, so it must be specific to Windows, or TeXstudio, or both. As I don't work in your environment, I wouldn't be able to test my answer. Moreover, in the end you solved your problem yourself, after discussing it with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general approach taken in the question is sound, but `bibtex` on Windows does not want the input to include the **.aux** extension. Removing this resolved the question.

For completeness, here's a MWE that compiles to two different pdfs (only tested with TexStudio on Windows). This solutions also incorporates the suggestion proposed by @gernot.

**a.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{substr}
\IfSubStringInString{\detokenize{solutions}}{\jobname}
    {\def\solutions{true}}
    {\def\solutions{false}}%
\usepackage[solutions=\solutions]{exframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
Test \cite{ref1}.
\end{problem}

\begin{solution}
Solution \cite{ref2}.
\end{solution}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

**refs.bib**

```
@misc{ref1,
author = {A},
title = {Ref 1.},
year = {}
}

@misc{ref2,
author = {B},
title = {Ref 2.},
year = {}
}
```

To compile (on TexStudio/Windows):

**pdflatex**

```
pdflatex.exe %.tex | pdflatex.exe %.tex --jobname=%-solutions
```

**bibtex**

```
bibtex.exe % | bibtex.exe %-solutions
```